# Nested applicative functors of different types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, monad-transformers, applicative

I'd like to make the nested applicative functors of different types. For example, nested simple functors of different types (in ghci) work fine:

```
Prelude> ((+2) <$>) <$> (Just [1..4])
Just [3,4,5,6]
```

But for applicative functors of different types:

```
Prelude> ((*) <$>)  <$> (Just [1,2,3]) <*> (Just [4,5,6,7])

<interactive>:56:1: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Integer -> Integer]' with `[Integer] -> b'
```

isn't working! I want to obtain something like this:

```
Just [4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,12,15,18,21]
```

I know that applicative functors have intermediate position between functors and monads. And I can see this exercise as preliminary before topic about monad transformers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you want:

```
liftA2 (*) <$> Just [1, 2, 3] <*> Just [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or:

```
liftA2 (liftA2 (*)) (Just [1, 2, 3]) (Just [4, 5, 6, 7])
```

The outer `… <$> … <*> …` or `liftA2` operates on `Maybe`, while the inner one operates on `[]`. If you didn’t know this, you could figure it out by asking GHCi for the type of what you should put there, for example with a typed hole:

```
:t _ <$> (Just [1 :: Int, 2, 3]) <*> (Just [4 :: Int, 5, 6, 7]) :: Maybe [Int]
```

It gives back:

```
_ :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

And the behaviour you want for combining the lists is `\ xs ys -> (*) <$> xs <*> ys`, which can be abbreviated `liftA2 (*)`. `((*) <$>)` or `fmap (*)` didn’t work because that’s only half of what you need: it operates on a single list (using `Functor`), while you want to combine two (using `Applicative`).

Of course, `liftA2 (liftA2 (*))` works on any two nested applicative functors whose elements are numeric:

```
(Applicative f, Applicative g, Num a)
  => f (g a) -> f (g a) -> f (g a)
```

For example, nested lists:

```
liftA2 (liftA2 (*)) [[1], [2], [3]] [[4, 5, 6]]
== [[4,5,6],[8,10,12],[12,15,18]]

-- (Transposing the inputs transposes the output.)
liftA2 (liftA2 (*)) [[1, 2, 3]] [[4], [5], [6]]
== [[4,8,12],[5,10,15],[6,12,18]]
```

Or lists of `Maybe`:

```
liftA2 (liftA2 (*)) [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3] [Just 4, Nothing, Just 6]
== [Just 4, Nothing, Just 6,
    Nothing, Nothing, Nothing,
    Just 12, Nothing, Just 18]
```

Or even something more exotic, like lists of functions:

```
($ (3, 5)) <$> (liftA2 (+) <$> [fst, snd] <*> [snd, fst])
== [fst (3, 5) + snd (3, 5),
    fst (3, 5) + fst (3, 5),
    snd (3, 5) + snd (3, 5),
    snd (3, 5) + fst (3, 5)]
== [3+5, 3+3, 5+5, 5+3]
== [8,6,10,8]
```

Comment: this variant works, too: `(liftA2 . liftA2) (*) (Just [1..3]) (Just [4..7])`

Answer (score 5):

Besides nesting lifts and fmaps, another option to compose applicative functors is the [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) newtype:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

for example:

```
ghci> let Compose result = (*) <$> Compose (Just [1,2,3]) <*> Compose (Just [4,5,6,7])
ghci> result
Just [4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,12,15,18,21]
```

`Applicative`s are so well-behaved that a single newtype suffices to compose any two types that are instances. And there are other ways to combine them besides nesting, like [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#t:Product) and [`Day`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html) convolution:

```
data Product f g a = Pair (f a) (g a)

data Day f g a = forall b c. Day (f b) (g c) (b -> c -> a)
```

`Monad`s do not compose as well though, so we need a *different* newtype for each monad in order to augment some other monad with the first monad's abilities. We call those newtypes monad transformers.

Answer (score 0):

We may also do this quite stragithforward with prelude functions. Your first part is nice though.

`((*) <$>)  <$> (Just [1,2,3])` with type `Num a => Maybe [a -> a]`

All we need is to fmap the applicative list in Maybe monad to a list in Maybe monad. So one approach could be to bind the first part to `(<$> Just [4, 5, 6, 7]) . (<*>) :: Num a => [a -> b] -> Maybe [b]`

```
((*) <$>)  <$> (Just [1,2,3]) >>= (<$> Just [4,5,6,7]) . (<*>)
```

yields to

```
Just [(1*),(2*),(3*)] >>= (<$> Just [4,5,6,7]) . (<*>)
```

yields to

```
([(1*),(2*),(3*)] <*>) <$> Just [4,5,6,7]
```

yields to

```
Just [4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,12,15,18,21]
```

Comment: While this solution applies to the specific example in the question, it doesn't answer the question in general, as it demands `Monad`.